# Using relative path for images

Tags: php, reference

I have following file sample structure for my website:

```
"**www.website.com/index.php**"
```

My all other pages are in "www.website.com"
I have a `header.php` for all pages located in `"**www.website.com/header.php**"`.

Now I have created an another new directory as:

```
**www.website.com/folder/index.php**
```

This internal index.php is also calling header.php with `**"../"**`
But I can't get the images which are called from header file for it.

Image path is like this: `**www.website.com/images**`

Can anyone tell me the Solution without using absolute path?

Comment: You may need to setup different `<base>` elements as needed by your system. For more information, [read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)

Answer (score 1):

Start the path with '/' (so without the '..') indicates that it should start looking from your root.

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend to use absolute path with predefined variable.

Something like this:

```
define('PATH', 'www.website.com')
```

and then use it

```
PATH."/images/"
```

That way, you can migrate your web elsewhere and you wont have to solve rpoblems with incorrect relative path (like eg. if you will use AJAX)

Comment: Hello
Thanks but it didn't work yet.

I put this code in my "header.php"

<?php define('PATH', 'www.website.com') ?>
     
     <div id="logo"><a href="index.php"><img src="PATH.images/logo2.png" alt="" title="" width="198" height="95" border="0" /></a></div>

Comment: you need to use PATH as PHP variable. img src=<?php echo PATH;?>/images/logo2.png ...

Answer (score 0):

The best way is:
If you are having common configuration file or if not then create it.
Define an Global variable for the image path:

```
define("IMAGE_PATH", "<image_path>");
```

Now you can you this "IMAGE_PATH" variable on files/application.
Benefit is when sometimes there is also minor changes, then need to check the whole application, but here you need to change this variable's value only.

Answer (score 0):

Set image path as `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/images'`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not only with images.

Any file which is called from external header.php is showing missing in internal directory.

I am again repeating my query.

I have two index.php files.
One is at root directory: **www.website.com/index.php**

and another is inside a folder like: **www.website.com/folder/index.php**

My header is in root directory which calls other files which are in root directory itself.
But Same header is used for index.php in "Folder".
There it shows the missing files.

I hope I an not confusing you. But please do reply for the solution.
Thanks